# WPF scaffolding?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, scaffolding

I'm trying to do some scaffolding around on WPF (and Silverlight later). Is there anything useful in the System.XAML namespace, or should I just use Linq2XML or something...?

By far System.XAML doesn't look useful, but I don't want to go the wrong direction.

Comment: I think I had to use the System.XAML some for specials using XPS files, but.... not much.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [XAML Power Toys](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/) a few times to do design-time scaffolding

Comment: Thx, but I'm not looking for a software, I want to do this myself!